# Structure of "artist exhibiting"

Tags: sentence-structure

What are the structure and meaning of the "exhibiting" in the following piece of a passage?

> Well, the exhibit that I want you to attend is coming up. It's already
>   started in fact, but it'll be at the gallery for the next month, which
>   should give you plenty of time to complete this assignment. The name
>   of the **artist exhibiting** there is Rose Frantzen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**exhibiting there** is a participle clause functioning as modifier of **the artist**.  It refers to an action being engaged in by **the artist**.

**To exhibit** (intransitive) in this context means to present one's works to an audience, as at an art gallery.

A paraphrase:

... the artist [who is] exhibiting  there.

Such clauses can refer to an action being undergone (passive):

> The toddler **being given an injection** is crying.

Compare:

The artist singing on the radio....

The musician playing on stage ...